# Refreshing background.js with info from popup.js - Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on some code that takes an input from a text box in a browser popup and then relays that input to the background.js in order to filter a webpage using that input.

If I hard code the filtering on background.js at the start then it works (because background.js runs once at the start), but if I put the filtering inside a function that receives the input from the text box in popup.js it doesn't work.

**popup.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#zim').click(function(){

    // Get User Input in Text Box
    var author = document.getElementById('author').value;

    // Pass author variable to background.js
    chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().StartFiltering(author);


    });
});
```

**background.js**

```
function StartFiltering(person){

    console.log("Starting Filtering");
    console.log("person: " +person);

    $( "a:contains('" + person + "')" ).closest('.post-wrapper.js_post-wrapper.wide.postlist-dense').remove();
    $( ".text-upper:contains('" + person + "')" ).closest('.post-wrapper.js_post-wrapper.wide.postlist-dense').remove();
    $( "a:contains('" + person + "')" ).closest('.post-wrapper.js_post-wrapper.postlist-dense').remove(); 

};
```

**manifest**

```
{
  "name": "Filter",
  "description": "Filter out authors on homepage",
  "version": "2.0",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery.js","background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "icons": {
      "128": "128.png"
   },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Filter",
    "default_icon": "filter.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2,
   "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": ["jquery.js","background.js"],
      "matches": [ "http://example.com/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

On background.js if I put the 3 lines of jQuery outside the function, and hard code in the "person" variable and reload the extension then it will filter the website correctly.  StartFiltering definitely runs, it definitely gets the "author" input from the user, but I think because background.js is only run at the start, it doesn't know to update the file?  I'm not sure! Fairly new to JS and coding in general!

Have searched around on here but I can't find anyone with the same problem!  Thanks in advance for any help!

**EDIT - SOLVED!**

So here's how I got this working...

After ExpertSystem pointed out that I was using background.js twice I cleaned up my manifest and file system so that I had 4 files: background.js, content.js, popup.js and the manifest. In my content_scripts section of the manifest I had jquery.js and content.js instead of background.js as before.

I had popup.js send a message to background.js whenever a user entered a value in the popup text box, this was done very simply as:

**popup.js**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: "new author", author:author});
```

I had background.js listen in for the message, then if the message type matched the one sent from popup.js then it would store the value of the blocked author in an array (because eventually I planned to keep a list of authors to filter), and send the array as a message:

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request,sender,sendResponse) {

        if(request.type == "new author") {
            blocked.push(request.author) 
        }

        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){

           chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id,{filter:"author",blocked:blocked})

        });
});
```

Then I had content.js listen in for the message:

**content.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg,sender){
    if (msg.filter == "author"){

        for (var i=0;i<msg.blocked.length;i++){
            startFiltering(msg.blocked[i]);     
        }   
    }
});
```

Still needs tweaking but I have all 3 pages communicating now!

Comment: Please, post the content of your manifest.

Comment: edited original post with manifest!  thanks!

Comment: What page are you trying to update ? The background page ???

Comment: User types value into popup.html page, that value is sent to background.js, which is updated with the value and then it applies a permanent removal "filter" via jquery so that whenever you go to http://example.com/* it filters out elements of the webpage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The problem**
You are using `background.js` both as your background-page (actually event-page) and as your content-script. So, when you visit **http://example.com/*** there are in fact two separate instances of `background.js`: One injected into the webpage and one in your generated background-page. (By the way, you can access your background-page at **chrome://extensions/** once you enable the developer mode.)

**The solution**

1. Don't use the same file as background-page **and** content script.
2. From `popup.html` pass a message to the content script injected into the webpage.
3. Have the content script do its magic (a.k.a. filtering).

**Example** (~ *untested code alert* ~):

```
// In popup
var author = ...;
chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(currentTab) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(currentTab.id, {
    action: 'filter',
    person: author
  });
});
```

.

```
// In content script
function filter(person) {
  $('a:contains(' + person + ')').
    closest('.post-wrapper.js_post-wrapper.wide.postlist-dense').
    remove();
  ...
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
  if ((msg.action === 'filter') && msg.person) {
    filter(msg.person);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance here!  It was invaluable to realise I was using two background.js files!  Once I cleaned that up I was able to get a working solution.  Will update the OP to show my solution, I had to play around with the code a bit to get the behaviour I wanted, but I got there in the end!

Comment: Hey, I know it's a long time ago, but I am still accepting upvotes if you really liked the answer :)